# Concisely adding variables to Django context dictionary

Tags: python, django, dictionary

The Django documentation suggests adding variables to the context dictionary in class based views as follows:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Call the base implementation first to get a context
        context = super(PublisherDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # Add in a QuerySet of all the books
        context['book_list'] = Book.objects.all()
        return context
```

I often have a lot of variables in my gather context function, so my code ends up looking like this:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PublisherDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        a = 2
        b = 'hello'
        c = 75 # temp variable, not wanted in context dict
        d = a * c

        context['a'] = a
        context['b'] = b
        context['d'] = d
        return context
```

To avoid adding each variable to the context dictionary on its own line, I've begun doing the following:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PublisherDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        a = 2
        b = 'hello'
        c = 75 # temp variable, not wanted in context dict
        d = a * c

        del c # delete any variables you don't want to add
        context.update({k:v for k,v in locals().copy().iteritems() if k[:2] != '__' and k != 'context'})
        return context
```

It seems to be working, but I'm not very familiar with locals(). Is there any reason why I shouldn't be doing it this way?

Comment: reasons not to do this... it's ugly, difficult to tell if you've done something wrong, difficult for others to read your code (and the copy() seems unnecessary).

Answer (score 0):

Use `locals` is such a bad idea. Just add to the context directly

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(PublisherDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    c = 75 # temp variable, not wanted in context dict

    context['a'] = 2
    context['b'] = 'hello'
    context['d'] = context['a'] * c
    return context
```